# Without using v-model, how to set default value of v-combobox?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating a form with a v-combobox component.

The :items are being retrieved from a table in my DB and I am using v-model to enter whatever is selected into a different table in the DB, so I'm using v-model to link to the new DB table.

I know that I can use v-model to set a default value (meaning that that item is automatically selected), however is there an alternative way to do this since I'm currently using v-model for connecting to the DB?

Form:

```
<v-combobox
    outlined
    :items="allTypes"
    v-model="plates[plates.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 1)].value"
    :search-input="search"
>
</v-combobox>
```

Comment: Have you tried just setting the component's `value` prop? Also, please stop hard coding ids in your templates, it's making me sad.

Comment: I've tried specifying value, item-value, item text and none worked so far, haha sorry I know hardcoding it is inefficient but in this case it's necessary (Styling purposes)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm following what you are trying to accomplish here... 
You want to have a default value set on your combo box that is not the true value of the data it is binded to with v-model?

I'm not sure that is a great idea. Because if the user wants the default value they will leave it, thinking "it's already set to what I want" but it's not actually an accurate reflection of the value they would be setting?

Either way, it sounds like you probably want to move the logic from your current v-model prop to a computed property, so you can separate the logic of getting and setting.

UPDATED With Code Snippet

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      // the set value, initially false to use as a 'has a value been set' flag
      setValue: false,
      // the default value shown before selection has happened
      defaultValue: "Pick a value (default)",
      // the options to select from
      allTypes: [
        'dogs',
        'cats',
        'hamsters',
        'something else',
      ],
      // your table data
      table: {
        value: "null (initially)"
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // the value the we are binding the combo box to
    comboBoxValue: {
      // the value to output
      get() {
        // if a value has not been set
        if (!this.setValue) {
          // return the default 
          return this.defaultValue;
        } else {
          // else return whatever you would like
          return this.setValue;
          /* plates[plates.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 1)].value */
        }
      },
      // the function that happens when the combo box is set
      set(val) {
        // val is the value the combox HAS been set to, not something you define here
        console.log(val);
        // update your table, pass in "val" the combo box value
        this.updateTable(val);
        // update the set value, combo box no longer show the default value
        this.setValue = val;

      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // some method to update your table
    updateTable(newValue) {
      alert('update table with value: ' + newValue)
      this.table.value = newValue;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            table value: {{table.value}}
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-combobox outlined :items="allTypes" v-model="comboBoxValue">
            </v-combobox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The if else statement works however I think I might be writing the set(value) function wrongly since it's not posting to the DB correctly: set(newValue) { var newValue = plates[plates.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 1)].value }

Comment: Yes, I think you are. With set(newValue){}, newValue is the value emitted by the combo box when it's changed. You don't need to declare it or assign it inside the function. 
For example:  
set(newValue){ console.log(newValue); }  
Will log the value in the combo box to the console each time it is set (a good first step to troubleshoot if you aren't seeing what you expect). 
It's hard to give more detail without seeing code. I'm not sure what 'allTypes' or 'plates' look like in your data.
But I believe you're looking for something along the lines of  
set(val){ /*databaseValue = val*/ };

Comment: I think this is the correct way to write it: newValue = this.plates.find(obj=>obj.id===8).data however, when I console log newValue then nothing is returned, not even an undefined. It tells me that for some reason I'm not actually assigning the value of NewValue (which correctly registers as the dropdown I select) to the data column in the db.

Comment: That may be the statement you want to use, but that's not how you use a set method in a computed property. The variable name you have in the parenthesis (newValue) is the value that the combo box **was** set to, not the value it **is going to be** set to. So you don't assign the value inside the set function, you work with value. 
I've updated my answer with a code snippet to give you a better example.

Comment: in your statement newValue = this.plates.find(obj=>obj.id===8).data, where is the value 8 coming from? I think you might want try something along the lines of 
data:{ setValue:false, defaultValue:"default", allTypes:[...] },computed:{ comboBoxValue:{ get(){ if(!this.setValue){ return(this.defaultValue;) }else{ return(this.plates.find(obj=>obj.id===this.setValue).data); } },set(val){ this.setValue=val; } }
so the get method either returns the default value or the plate data of the set value. But you will likely need to modify what field the combobox is using for the value.